# Controlling frequency of notifications received from device

Tags: azure, push-notification, uwp

Is there a way to control when and how often push notifications are received from the device?

I'm sending push notifications from Azure to Windows UWP device.  Notification is sent if temperature reaches a tag value or greater, tags are 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 etc

So device that subscribes to 20 will receive notification from server when temp is 20 or anything higher than 20.

However my problem is that the server updates every half hour and so if the temperature on one update is 23 then the next updates always stays above 20, the user keeps receiving push notifications. And its kind of not alerting them to anything new, just keeps sending the same message.

I want to be able for the user specify the following settings for notifications
because receiving a notification every half hour can get annoying and bother the user too often.

- notify always (already doing this)
- only notify for the first time you reach temperature 20 or greater

  OR
  notify me only once every 2 hours
- only notify during these times (9:00AM - 10:00pm) - I think this is easy to do, as I can unsubscribe to the notification I guess with a background task and then subscribe back to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm sending push notifications from Azure to Windows UWP device. Notification is sent if temperature reaches a tag value or greater, tags are 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 etc

As I known, you could leverage [Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) to send push notifications to a UWP app, and you could use [Routing and tag expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message) for pushing notifications to the specific sets of devices when sending the notification via Notification Hubs. But as the official tutorial states about [Tag expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message#tag-expressions):

> Tag expressions can **contain all Boolean operators, such as AND (&&), OR (||), and NOT (!)**. They can also contain parentheses. Tag expressions are limited to 20 tags if they contain only ORs; otherwise they are limited to 6 tags.

Per my understanding of your scenario, if the temperature is 28, then you need to compare with the supported tags and send the notification as follows:

`NotificationHubClient.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync("{toast}","(0||10||20)")`

> Is there a way to control when and how often push notifications are received from the device?

As I known, there is no build-in feature for you to achieve this purpose. Per my understanding, you need to use **Installations** model and store the device registration info (`InstallationId`, `user tags`, `LastPushNotificationDateTime`,etc.) in a data storage, then filter the  registration records for the valid InstallationIds (devices) that have not received the notification, then use the following method to send a notification to the specific installation (device) as follows:

`_hubclient.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync("payload", "$InstallationId:{" + installationId + "}");`

Additionally, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) about devices registration management with notification hubs. Also, there is a official [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948105.aspx) about Azure Notification Hubs: Best Practices for Managing Devices, you could refer to it.